# How can I get this custom post type permalink structure? %custom_post_type%-%taxonomy%-%term-postname%

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, terms, hierarchical

Please help - I've tried almost everything and I'm absolutely lost!

I'm desperate to get the following permalink structure set up:

ladsholidayguide.com/custom_post/taxonomy/term/postname

For example: ladsholidayguide.com/reviews/venue/clubs/liquid-nightclub

I've tried using the Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin, yet this option doesn't work either

Check this and the custom taxonomy's permalinks will be:
www.ladsholidayguide.com/post_type/taxonomy/term/postname/

For some reason

This works fine.
ladsholidayguide.com/reviews/venues/junkyard-golf-london/

This doesn't (I get 404)
ladsholidayguide.com/reviews/venues/restaurants/imads-syrian-kitchen/

It seems the term / subcategory breaks it.

Below is the code used: If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know.

```
/** Custom Post Type Post Type: Reviews: **/

function cptui_register_my_cpts_reviews() {

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Reviews', '' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Review', '' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Reviews', '' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "reviews", "with_front" => false ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "review" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "reviews", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_reviews' );


    /** Taxonomy: Review (not reviews due to custom post type name). **/

function cptui_register_my_taxes_review() {

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Review', '' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'review', '' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Review', '' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "label" => "Review",
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'review', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ),
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( "review", array( "reviews" ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_review' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is what you are looking for:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/